# A Combinatorial Sum!

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Is there a closed form formula for the following sum

\begin{equation}
F(x;n,m)=\sum_{k=0}^{\min\{n,m\}} {n \choose k}{m \choose k}k!\ x^{k}=n! \, m!\sum_{k=0}^{\min\{n,m\}}\frac{1}{k!(n-k)!(m-k)!} x^{k}
\end{equation}

where $k$ runs from zero to the minimum of $n$ and $m$.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\displaystyle{a\choose b}=0$ for *integers* $b>a$, so we can write, without loss of generalization, that $$\begin{align}F_{~m,~n}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^m\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^n\cdots&=(-x)^n~~U\bigg(-n,~m-(n-1);~-\frac1x\bigg)=\\&=(-x)^m~U\bigg(-m,~n-(m-1);~-\frac1x\bigg),\end{align}$$ where ***U*** is the [confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function).

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, I don't see how your expression results in my sum...!!! Are you referring to the first type confluent hypergeometric functions or the second type? Also, this would basically be just giving the sum a name, in this case $U(a,b,z)$. It is not a closed form formula, am I right?

Comment: @Ben: It's as closed as it gets.